# Organize images of continents neatly together

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I cut out images of continents and saved them as png files. My goal is to organize them neatly back together with html, css, bootstrap, whatever really.

I cut the images so I could create different links for each continent.

As of now I used bootstrap.css to set them together but cannot figure out the html and css to get them to come together neatly.

```
<div class="row-fluid" >
    <div class="span12" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; height: 150px; text-align:center">

            <img src="images/NorthAmerica.png" style= "width: 300px; float: left;" />


            <img src="images/Europe.png" style="width: 300px; " />


            <img src="images/Asia.png" style=" width: 300px; " />


            <img src="images/SouthAmerica.png" style=" width: 300px; float: left; " />


            <img src="images/Africa.png" style=" width: 300px; " />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have heard of using z-index and position: absolute; but I cannot get them be neatly together. There has to be a tool to organize images in a table that will generate the code or something I hope. (By the way, I do not want to use svg as this map will only have 5 links)

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps you should keep the original image, and create an area map. It may be out of fashion, but it's been around since the dawn of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it without cutting the image too. The technique is called image mapping. Only problem is that you need to know the coordinates of the different continents, but imo, it's much easier than what you are doing.

[Here's some reference](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks07.htm)
[A image mapping tool](http://www.image-maps.com/) to ease out the process of image mapping.

Comment: Yeah. [Here](http://www.image-maps.com/). Though I havent used it before, but friends recommend it.

Comment: Awesome, I spend hours doing svg and parsing it to .js. Then I tried the manual cutting of the continents for the past few hours. What a day. Thank you for the information, I just tried a quick image mapping tool and got the coordinate code. I will sleep much better now and enjoy my weekend! :D